# Add Game Center Objective C Sprite Kit report Scores

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, game-center

I have made a helper singleton Class to implement Game Center. Then I am calling the method to authenticate the player in my AppDelegate.

If I start the app, all good!

Next step: I want to report my scores. I have this method as report Score

```
+ (void) reportScore: (Float64) score forIdentifier: (NSString*) identifier
{
GKScore* highScore = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:identifier];
highScore.value = score;
[GKScore reportScores:@[highScore] withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error in reporting scores: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

}

I call it when I have GameOver and shortly before switching to my GameOverScene:

```
[GCTurnBasedMatchHelperr reportScore:self.scoring forIdentifier:@"score"];
```

I am playing with a Sandbox Test User. If I go to game center then to the leaderboard of my game, it says: No Scores.

After that, I would like to display the leaderboard and the scores somehow.

If you need any more code, go to this github: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1881303471cb9790af0b

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: May I have to add the <GKGameCenterControllerDelegate> for it?

But in which class?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did a really simple mistake, I just used a wrong identifier when I report the score. It is not score it was Score.. .